# Why do libraries prefer to obfuscate the code or provide no debug information instead of creating a special version containing debug information?

Tags: c++, debugging, software-quality

In libraries, we often see specific code for debug.
It can sometimes really mess up the code.

I don't see libraries that use 2 versions of the code.
1 version without debug information and 1 other with debug information.

There are advantages and disadvantages:

For a large library, this could considerably increase the size of the code and force to maintain 2 times the same code.

Besides that, it would be possible to have a very complete debug with special structures, many different checks that can be defined via macros
and make the code much easier to debug.

Why do libraries prefer to obfuscate the code or provide no debug information instead of creating a special version containing debug information?

For example:

```cpp
#ifdef NDEBUG

void send_message(int fd, const char* buffer, int len) {
  int total = 0;
  while (total < len) {
    int n = write(fd, buffer + total, len - total);
    total += n;
  }
}
#else

void print_and_exit(const char* message) {
  std::cerr << message << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}

#ifdef ENABLE_WARNING
void warning(const char* message) { std::cerr << message << std::endl; }
#else
void warning(const char* message) {}
#endif

void send_message(int fd, const char* buffer, int len) {
  if (fd < 0) {
    print_and_exit("fd is invalid");
  }
  if (!buffer) {
    print_and_exit("NULL buffer");
  }
  if (len <= 0) {
    warning("buffer size <= 0");
  }
  int total = 0;
  while (total < len) {
    int n = write(fd, buffer + total, len - total);
    total += n;
  }
}
#endif
```

The debug code is in the same file but we can imagine separate files that are included according to what is defined by the user

Comment: I have seen plenty of (precompiled) libraries that provide debug and non-debug files to link against. Though in the source code that is usually done exactly the way you see it, via preprocessor defines. I also don't understand what you mean by *"It can sometimes really mess up the code"*

Comment: Do you have an example library?
Macros in structures and functions that make the code less clear.
It's a personal opinion but from my research, I'm not the only one to think so.

Comment: It looks like you are really talking about libraries providing *logging* information with *debug* level logging. Also not sure why a library would **ever** call `exit()`.

Comment: Likewise. Further, the posted example is trivial. In reality a big reason *that* practice is rarely seen/wanted is due to the major investment of managing *two* code bases. It's hard enough fixing *one* version of a highly complicated set of functions, much less more-than-doubling the code footprint. The example you're giving, btw, isn't so much debug vs. not; it is *instrumented* vs. not.

Comment: @Galik I only gave a simple example to clarify my question.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes as I say, now twice the same code can be annoying.
It seems to me that it could help to debug a very complicated function which does not work as it should.

Comment: I'm still unsure why you consider this "obfuscation" (it's really not) or why exactly this is a practical problem. The debug defines are there exactly to help with debugging and should not interfere when doing step through debugging anyway